# Too Fast, Too Fourier: FFT Code Golf

Tags: code-golf, math, complex-numbers

Implement the Fast Fourier Transform in the fewest possible characters.

Rules:

- Shortest solution wins
- It can be assumed that the input is a 1D array whose length is a power of two.
- You may use the algorithm of your choice, but the solution must actually be a Fast Fourier Transform, not just a naive Discrete Fourier Transform (that is, it must have asymptotic computation cost of \$O(N \log N)\$)
- the code should implement the standard forward Fast Fourier Transform, the form of which can be seen in equation (3) of [this Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteFourierTransform.html),

$$F_n = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}f_ke^{-2\pi ink/N}$$

- Using an FFT function from a pre-existing standard library or statistics package is not allowed.  The challenge here is to succinctly *implement* the FFT algorithm itself.

Comment: This is underspecified. At the very least you need to define the normalisation factors, and you also ought to be aware that any ambiguity will be wilfully misinterpreted. E.g. is "Implement" satisfied by the answer "`FFT` (3 chars): it's in the standard library"? Some test cases would be good too.

Comment: Does it matter about the order of the output elements, i.e. do we need to implement bit reversed unscrambling or can we leave the output in scrambled order ?

Comment: See the edits to the rules.  The output should be a list/array with values ordered according to the indices in the standard DFT expression, referenced above.

Comment: VTC as no IO requirements mentioned.

Comment: Can you post some example inputs and outputs so we can test our implementations?

Comment: Title should have been "Fast and Fourier-s" (Fast and Furious).

Comment: Where are the tests cases?

Comment: Instead of point to the page fft O(n^2) why not point to the page fast Fourier transform with O(n*log_2(n))

Comment: If the problem for fft is the speed why not use some other tag and not "codegolf" tag? I not had identified the problem where this fft is slow... Can someone give some input where this fft functions are slow?

Answer (score 12):

## Mathematica, 95 bytes

Another implementation of the Cooley–Tukey FFT with help from @[chyaong](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7254/chyaong).

```
{n=Length@#}~With~If[n>1,Join[+##,#-#2]&[#0@#[[;;;;2]],#0@#[[2;;;;2]]I^Array[-4#/n&,n/2,0]],#]&
```

#### Ungolfed

```
FFT[x_] := With[{N = Length[x]},
  If[N > 1,
    With[{a = FFT[ x[[1 ;; N ;; 2]] ], 
          b = FFT[ x[[2 ;; N ;; 2]] ] * Table[E^(-2*I*Pi*k/N), {k, 0, N/2 - 1}]},
      Join[a + b, a - b]],
    x]]
```

Comment: I think `#[[;;;;2]]==#[[1;;N;;2]]` and `[[2;;;;2]]==[[2;;N;;2]]`.

Comment: 101 characters：`With[{L=Length@#},If[L>1,Join[+##,#-#2]&[#0@#[[;;;;2]],#0@#[[2;;;;2]]E^(-2I*Pi(Range[L/2]-1)/L)],#]]&`

Comment: Nice, you can condense another anonymous function inside it without conflicting with the recursive one. Also learned that Part fills in missing indices. We can take it further using Unicode.

Answer (score 9):

## Python, <strike>166</strike> <strike>151</strike> 150 characters

This uses the radix-2 Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm

```
from math import*
def F(x):N=len(x);t=N<2or(F(x[::2]),F(x[1::2]));return N<2and x or[
a+s*b/e**(2j*pi*n/N)for s in[1,-1]for(n,a,b)in zip(range(N),*t)]
```

Testing the result

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.random(512)
>>> np.allclose(F(x), np.fft.fft(x))
True
```

Comment: 2 things: it's typically best to use `from x import*`, and `sum(([x for x in y] for y in z),[])` is longer than `[x for y in z for x in y]`.

Comment: Thanks - that saves 15 characters! 11 more and it's a tweet.

Comment: Oh, that's definitely possible.  Often when you find one improvement, an old one becomes a stumbling block.

Answer (score 9):

## J, 37 bytes

```
_2&(0((+,-)]%_1^i.@#%#)&$:/@|:]\)~1<#
```

An improvement after a few years. Still uses the Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm.

Saved 4 bytes using *e*<sup>*πi*</sup> = -1, thanks to @[Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYu7DoJAFAV7vuJE5BXxuu9lN2qwsrewEimMRG0saCjEX1/BnEwmU5xX6LHzYJgIrUhzluercl00ScuvT6rjJC7Spd/UH99cii/fxqGIFoSsm28ZSowefTTMJTASDqfjObrfHm90KS0o3WMIgeO/yQISKmgSyggDSY5ZNdsKKTU0WaWEgyLrKomKpOKWT6mMrTQYWcO4dD8)

### Usage

```
   f =: _2&(0((+,-)]%_1^i.@#%#)&$:/@|:]\)~1<#
   f 1 1 1 1
4 0 0 0
   f 1 2 3 4
10 _2j2 _2 _2j_2
   f 5.24626 3.90746 3.72335 5.74429 4.7983 8.34171 4.46785 0.760139
36.9894 _6.21186j0.355661 1.85336j_5.74474 7.10778j_1.13334 _0.517839 7.10778j1.13334 1.85336j5.74474 _6.21186j_0.355661
```

### Explanation

```
_2&(0((+,-)]%_1^i.@#%#)&$:/@|:]\)~1<#  Input: array A
                                    #  Length
                                  1<   Greater than one?
_2&(                            )~     Execute this if true, else return A
_2                            ]\         Get non-overlapping sublists of size 2
    0                       |:           Move axis 0 to the end, equivalent to transpose
                          /@             Reduce [even-indexed, odd-indexed]
                       &$:               Call recursively on each 
                   #                     Get the length of the odd list
                i.@                      Range from 0 to that length exclusive
                    %#                   Divide each by the odd length
             _1^                         Compute (-1)^x for each x
           ]                             Get the odd list
            %                            Divide each in that by the previous
       +                                 Add the even values and modified odd values
         -                               Subtract the even values and modified odd values
        ,                                Join the two lists and return
```

Comment: See also, this: http://blog.ndpar.com/2014/10/11/dft-j/

Answer (score 6):

### Python 3: <strike>140</strike> <strike>134</strike> 113 characters

Short version - short and sweet, fits in a tweet (with thanks to [miles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6710/miles)):

```python
from math import*
def f(v):
 n=len(v)
 if n<2:return v
 a,b=f(v[::2])*2,f(v[1::2])*2;return[a[i]+b[i]/1j**(i*4/n)for i in range(n)]
```

(In Python 2, `/` is truncating division when both sides are integers. So we replace `(i*4/n)` by `(i*4.0/n)`, which bumps the length to 115 chars.)

Long version - more clarity into the internals of the classic Cooley-Tukey FFT:

```python
import cmath
def transform_radix2(vector):
    n = len(vector)
    if n <= 1:  # Base case
        return vector
    elif n % 2 != 0:
        raise ValueError("Length is not a power of 2")
    else:
        k = n // 2
        even = transform_radix2(vector[0 : : 2])
        odd  = transform_radix2(vector[1 : : 2])
        return [even[i % k] + odd[i % k] * cmath.exp(i * -2j * cmath.pi / n) for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Shortened to [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYpBCsMgEADvvmKPrhWCJifbvEQ8GKrtlrIJYiF9vTG0l2EGZvvW58pja/eUIcsdnQCe34m7CqAMfLOupPopDLuAqJe5X945G1BZfbr5x/W3@egpXJaOwbyUkpOigTGvBQiIoUR@JMkY2laIq8zSG231qKeA2A4) using `e^(-2j * pi * i / n) = (-1)^(2 * i / n) = (1j)^(4 * i / n)`

Comment: @miles Very impressive observation, thank you! Having repeatedly implemented DFTs for over a decade, I got obsessed with sin/cos/exp and forgot that simple powers of i can be used. I edited my answer to incorporate the new insight and credit you.

Comment: `e^(-2j * pi * i / n) = (-1)^(2 * i / n) = (1j)^(4 * i / n)` Should be
`e^(2j * pi * i / n) = (-1)^(2 * i / n) = (1j)^(4 * i / n)`?

Comment: @Hunaphu On what basis do you say that? The [standard DFT formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition) uses `-2j`. The inverse DFT uses `+2j`.

Comment: Sorry, I was not commenting your code (which I have no reason to question) but the statement `e^(-2j * pi * i / n) = (-1)^(2 * i / n)` which is false.

Comment: @Hunaphu Oh, I think you're right. But notice that in my short code, I *divide* by `1j**(i*4/n)`, whereas in my long code I *multiply* by `cmath.exp(i * -2j * cmath.pi / n)`. The division effectively negates the exponent.

Comment: That was what I suspected, but I wanted to study your code and was unsure of that part. Thanks for an interesting answer!

Answer (score 5):

#### R: <strike>142</strike> <s>133</s> <s>99</s> 95 bytes

Thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312) for helping me shaving down <s>32</s> 36 bytes!

```
f=function(x,n=sum(x|1),y=1:(n/2)*2)`if`(n>1,f(x[-y])+c(b<-f(x[y]),-b)*exp(-2i*(y/2-1)*pi/n),x)
```

An additional trick here is to use the main function default arguments to instantiate some variables.
Usage is still the same:

```
x = c(1,1,1,1)
f(x)
[1] 4+0i 0+0i 0+0i 0+0i
```

**4-year old version at 133 bytes:**

```
f=function(x){n=length(x);if(n>1){a=Recall(x[seq(1,n,2)]);b=Recall(x[seq(2,n,2)]);t=exp(-2i*(1:(n/2)-1)*pi/n);c(a+b*t,a-b*t)}else{x}}
```

With indentations:

```
f=function(x){
    n=length(x)
    if(n>1){
        a=Recall(x[seq(1,n,2)])
        b=Recall(x[seq(2,n,2)])
        t=exp(-2i*(1:(n/2)-1)*pi/n)
        c(a+b*t,a-b*t)
        }else{x}
    }
```

It uses also Cooley-Tukey algorithm. The only tricks here are the use of function `Recall` that allows recursivity and the use of R vectorization that shorten greatly the actual computation.

Usage:

```
x = c(1,1,1,1)
f(x)
[1] 4+0i 0+0i 0+0i 0+0i
```

Comment: Four years later, and we get it down to [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYs7DoMwEAXvQvWesyu0LqOQi0Q0WBi5yIZ8kFxwd4dE081oXq3lIW@ePuXhqOxK7gC/6Hu7o@5GXk0y6m051PyEiUvkyFMCpuEXdBlJ0Ylhris0lgA7w/tINYa19E6pbBnpmP@Q7Qs "R – Try It Online"). Not 100% sure why you used `Recall` as it's a named function already, but hey, it's easy to golf in hindsight! :) +1, very nice.

Comment: Yes `Recall` is now unnecessary, indeed. I noticed that a few months ago but was too lazy to change it :) I'll modify it.

Comment: Very nice! I squeezed [another 4 bytes out!](https://tio.run/##HcdNCsIwEAbQ63yTzhAmy2K8iAilwYEsHItaSKB3jz@81XuOYdl2L@/6cDT2/NrvaIcS96wzPCYKiZZqC/ysbGgX6VeaCtaT/PYNy0rh1jZIqgE9JlEKW41O3GgYCpT/iMYH "R – Try It Online"), putting this on par with Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about putting `y` up there but didn't notice it could be use for the `exp(...)` part as well.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 134

This borrows heavily from jakevdp's solution, so I've set this one to a community wiki.

```
from math import*
F=lambda x:x*(len(x)<2)or[a+s*b/e**(2j*pi*n/len(x))for s in(1,-1)for n,(a,b)in
enumerate(zip(F(x[::2]),F(x[1::2])))]
```

Changes:

-12 chars: kill `t`.

```
def F(x):N=len(x);t=N<2or(F(x[::2]),F(x[1::2]));return ... in zip(range(N),*t)]
def F(x):N=len(x);return ... in zip(range(N),F(x[::2]),F(x[1::2]))]
```

-1 char: exponent trick, `x*y**-z == x/y**z`  (this could help some others)

```
...[a+s*b*e**(-2j*pi*n/N)...
...[a+s*b/e**(2j*pi*n/N)...
```

-2 char: replace `and` with `*`

```
...return N<2and x or[
...return x*(N<2)or[
```

+1 char: `lambda`ize, killing `N`

```
def F(x):N=len(x);return x*(N<2)or[a+s*b/e**(2j*pi*n/N) ... zip(range(N) ...
F=lambda x:x*(len(x)<2)or[a+s*b/e**(2j*pi*n/len(x)) ... zip(range(len(x)) ...
```

-2 char: use `enumerate` instead of `zip(range(len(`

```
...for(n,a,b)in zip(range(len(x)),F(x[::2]),F(x[1::2]))]
...for n,(a,b)in enumerate(zip(F(x[::2]),F(x[1::2])))]
```

Comment: I think that this is no longer a fast fourier transform, though... by "killing t" you added in some unnecessary calculations which move it from O[N log(N)] to O[N^2]

Comment: It appears that I cannot downvote my own post.  You are correct, I exchanged the loop order and killed the performance.  I will leave this up for now, in case I find a way to fix it.

Comment: 101 bytes with ``f=lambda x:x*(len(x)<2)or[u+v/1j**(4*i/len(x))for i,(u,v)in enumerate(zip(f(x[::2])*2,f(x[1::2])*2))]``

Comment: You can replace `for s in(1,-1)for` with `for s in 1,-1for` or even, if order does not matter, `for s in-1,1for`.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 259

```c
typedef double complex cplx;
void fft(cplx buf[],cplx out[],int n,int step){
if(step < n){
fft(out, buf,n, step * 2);
fft(out+step,buf+step,n,step*2);
for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2*step){
cplx t=cexp(-I*M_PI*i/n)*out[i+step];
buf[i/2]=out[i]+t;
buf[(i+n)/2]=out[i]-t;
}}}
```

The problem is, such implementations are useless, and straightforward algorithm is MUCH faster.

Comment: You can remove some more whitespace to get a lower amout of characters, for example the `step < n` can be changed into `step<n` and the `step * 2` can be changed into `step*2`.

Comment: all the variables and functions and typedefs should have one-letter names to save a lot of chars

Comment: You had someone suggest a bunch of improvements for this. Take a look at them here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17119

Comment: You can remove all newlines, newlines are useless in C

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg Not all newlines are useless. They are needed for directives like #include, #define, #if, etc.

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, <s>128</s> <s>118</s> <s>107</s> <s>102</s> <s>101</s> <s>94</s> 93 bytes

EDIT6: thanks @algmyr for another byte!

```
function Y=f(Y);
n=numel(Y);
k=2:2:n;
if k;
   c=f(Y(k-1));
   d=f(Y(k)).*i.^(2*(2-k)/n);
   Y=[c+d;c-d];
end
```

EDIT5: Still getting shorter:) thanks to @sanchises

```
function Y=f(Y)
n=numel(Y);
k=2:2:n;
if k;
   c=f(Y(k-1));
   d=f(Y(k)).*(-1).^((2-k)/n);
   Y=[c+d;c-d];
end
```

EDIT4: Yay, -1 character more (could aslo have done without the `k`):

```
function Y=f(Y)
n=numel(Y);
if n>1;
   k=2:2:n;
   c=f(Y(k-1));
   d=f(Y(k)).*(-1).^((k/2-1)*2/n)';
   Y=[c+d;c-d];
end
```

EDIT2/3: Thanks for @sanchises for further improvements!

```
function Y=f(Y)
n=numel(Y);  
if n>1;
   c=f(Y(1:2:n));
   d=f(Y(2:2:n)).*(-1).^(-(0:n/2-1)*2/n).';
   Y=[c+d;c-d]; 
end
```

EDIT: Could make some improvements, and noticed that the scaling constant is not required.

This is the expanded version, character count is valid if you remove the newlines/spaces. (Works only for column vectors.)

```
function y=f(Y)
n=numel(Y);  
y=Y;
if n>1;
   c=f(Y(1:2:n));
   d=f(Y(2:2:n));
   n=n/2;
   d=d.*exp(-pi*i*(0:n-1)/n).';
   y=[c+d;c-d]; 
end
```

Comment: Tip: you can combine the two `d=` lines into one: `m=n/2;d=f(Y(2:2:n)).*exp(-pi*i*(0:m-1)/m).';`. Furthermore, consider changing `y=f(Y)` to `Y=f(Y)` and remove line 3 (and promise you'll never do that outside of code-golf)

Comment: Oh thanks! Does `function Y = f(Y)` have any disadvanteages other than unreadability?

Comment: Well, MATLAB will never complain about a return value, even if Y is never changed. It is *slightly* faster though, so I guess it isn't so bad after all for some purposes (i.e. a function that almost never changes the input variable)

Comment: Now, for shaving off more: `m=n/2` could be removed, and instead `m` replaced by `n/2` and `n*2` respectively. And then, I strongly believe, the program is as short as could be in MATLAB.

Comment: Yay, finally under 100=) thanks!

Comment: Your believe was wrong, I could strip one more character! =P

Comment: Always happy to be proven wrong :) Although, I'm afraid you'll have to recount... I'm counting 102 characters in your latest version.

Comment: You're right, we've still got 2 characters to go. EDIT: *one* more to go=)

Comment: I know this is very old, but I just realized that this can still be golfed. Instead of `if n>1`, you can do `if k` if you move the definition of k outside the `if` statement. Furthermore, you can change `((k/2-1)*2/n)'` to `((2-k)/n)` (note the absence of the conjungate operator).

Comment: Since this is necroposted already, why not another improvement? By default the variable `i` is the imaginary unit, so `(-1).^((2-k)/n)` can be written as `i.^(2*(2-k)/n)` saving 1 character.

Comment: Yeah, why not? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: *And then, I strongly believe, the program is as short as could be in MATLAB. – Sanchises Mar 8 '15 at 21:05* Famous last words...

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, <s>31</s> <s>30</s> <s>28</s> 26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
LḶ÷$N-*×,N$+ḷF
s2Zß€ç/µ¹Ṗ?
```

This uses the Cooley-Tukey radix-2 recursive algorithm. For an un-golfed version, see my [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12429/6710) in Mathematica.

[Try it online](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=TOG4tsO3JE4tKsOXLE4kK-G4t0YKczJaw5_igqzDpy_CtcK54bmWPw&input=&args=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDRd) or [Verify multiple test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=TOG4tsO3JE4tKsOXLE4kK-G4t0YKczJaw5_igqzDpy_CtcK54bmWPwrDh8WS4bmYJOKCrGrigbc&input=&args=W1sxLCAxLCAxLCAxXSwKIFsxLCAyLCAzLCA0XSwKIFs1LjI0NjI2LCAzLjkwNzQ2LCAzLjcyMzM1LCA1Ljc0NDI5LCA0Ljc5ODMsIDguMzQxNzEsIDQuNDY3ODUsIDAuNzYwMTM5XV0).

### Explanation

```
LḶ÷$N-*×,N$+ḷF  Helper link. Input: lists A and B
L               Get the length of A
   $            Operate on that length
 Ḷ                Make a range [0, 1, ..., length-1]
  ÷               Divide each by length
    N           Negate each
     -          The constant -1
      *         Compute -1^(x) for each x in that range
       ×        Multiply elementwise between that range and B, call it B'  
          $     Operate on that B'
         N        Negate each
        ,         Make a list [B', -B']
            ḷ   Get A
           +    Add vectorized, [B', -B'] + A = [A+B', A-B']
             F  Flatten that and return

s2Zß€ç/µ¹Ṗ?  Main link. Input: list X
         Ṗ   Curtail - Make a copy of X with the last value removed
          ?  If that list is truthy (empty lists are falsey)
       µ       Parse to the left as a monad
s2             Split X into sublists of length 2
  Z            Transpose them to get [even-index, odd-index]
   ß€          Call the main link recursively on each sublist
     ç/        Call the helper link as a dyad on the sublists and return
             Else
        ¹      Identity function on X and return
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>188 186 184</s> 183 bytes

```c
#define d(a,b,c)f(a,b,c,1,0)
f(a,b,c,n,k)_Complex*a,*b;{_Complex z[c];*b=*a;if(n<c)for(f(a,z,c,n*2),f(a+n,z+n,c,n*2);k<c;k+=n*2)b[k+c>>1]=z[k]*2-(b[k/2]=z[k]+z[k+n]/cpow(1i,2.*k/c));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVDBasMwDL33K0RHwY7dNUnDKLjuZZ@RmWG7cTFJnNB0bKT015fZzVo22NihO0jPT5b0JOn5TuthuNsWxroCtkhSRTU2I9KExnhyIY6W@PmxqduqeIskjRQ7Xij0uRYsUjySzBrk1r5Fs0ehsg@VUYqpJ8TR3tsYYOVas5Lw8FZ5SfRmkwje56WI0jnykUU6UuIdcWKh2@YVJZam91G50Biz03DVl3kSCza5cjVy6w5QS@sQPk7AJ8WC@8zg0uCWgifMf4RZIeRa4BAzD2vIPBACGEIlQLv3/wbBdGbIzFiYUtD7QlZI5lZgT2wtdyMBHHqevLUvhw5Np2e@RSApKAoZvlVSfZVUP0k@uVH0c1m/Z8zO2yfsvHrqIRN86eFB8Cyk1kXdFQcUJowpdLYvGgPq11lX/3ce@H6f1c2af98nXOc0vGtTyV03zKv6Aw)

Slightly golfed less

```c
#define d(a,b,c)f(a,b,c,1,0)
f(a,b,c,n,k)_Complex*a,*b;{
  _Complex z[c];
  *b=*a;
  if(n<c)
    for(f(a,z,c,n*2),f(a+n,z+n,c,n*2);k<c;k+=n*2)
      b[k+c>>1]=z[k]*2-(b[k/2]=z[k]+z[k+n]/cpow(1i,2.*k/c));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pari/GP, 76 characters

```
X(v)=my(t=-2*Pi*I/#v,s);vector(#v,k,s=t*(k-1);sum(n=0,#v-1,v[n+1]*exp(s*n)))
```

Usage

```
X([1,1,1,1])
%2 = [4.000000000000000000000000000, 0.E-27 + 0.E-28*I, 0.E-28 + 0.E-27*I, 0.E-27 + 0.E-28*I]
```

Comment: Isn't this the naive DFT? (ie theta(N^2))

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>109 103 101</s> 100 bytes

```matlab
f(f=@(f)@(x,n=rows(x)){@(d=f(f)(x(k=2:2:n)).*i.^((k*2-4)/n)')[d+(c=f(f)(x(k-1)));c-d],x}{1+(n<2)}())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BCsIwGIPvPkVv@7N1da3zMi30PUYF2SzIoAMVLYw9ey0diAS@QBLIPLyu71t0WggRHTltyMFQ4F4/5s@TArAYGnWqQIEmrTrVeUCUd3EhmkpVt9h7FOjHiobfrpYATkM9Wh7WRVbkzworAemkt9glHjeTrPmXLbaUs4YzlXnIbHku4xc)

Ooooo do my eyes bleed from this <s>recursive</s> accursed lambda. Large parts of this were lifted from @flawr's answer.

```matlab
f(                                          % lambda function
  f=@(f)                                    % defined in its own argument list, 
                                            % accepts itself as parameter (for recursion)
    @(x,n=rows(x)){                         % calls another lambda,
                                            % 2nd parameter is just to define a variable
      @(d=f(f)(x(k=2:2:n)).*i.^((k*2-4)/n)')% 1/4 of FFT (argument just defines a variable)
        [d+(c=f(f)(x(k-1)));                % 2/4 of FFT
         c-d                                % 4/4 of FFT
        ],                                  % This is in a @()[] to inhibit evaluation
                                            % unless actually called
      x                                     % FFT of length 1
    }{1+(n<2)}                              % if len(x)==1, return x
                                            % else return [d+c;c-d]
  ()                                        % this is probably important too
)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you did but I like it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 58 chars, 116 bytes

```
{1≥k←≢⍵:⍵⋄(∇⍵[y∼⍨⍳k])(+,-)(∇⍵[y←2×⍳t])×0J1*t÷⍨2-2×⍳t←⌊k÷2}
```

test

```
  f←{1≥k←≢⍵:⍵⋄(∇⍵[y∼⍨⍳k])(+,-)(∇⍵[y←2×⍳t])×0J1*t÷⍨2-2×⍳t←⌊k÷2}
  f 1 1 1 1
4J0 0J0 0J0 0J0 
  f 1 2 3 4
10J0 ¯2J2 ¯2J0 ¯2J¯2 
  f 1J1 2 ¯2J1  9
10J2 3J7 ¯12J2 3J¯7 
  f 5.24626,3.90746,3.72335,5.74429,4.7983,8.34171,4.46785,0.760139
36.989359J0 ¯6.211855215J0.3556612739 1.85336J¯5.744741 7.107775215J¯1.133338726 ¯0.517839J0 
  7.107775215J1.133338726 1.85336J5.744741 ¯6.211855215J¯0.3556612739
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom,  <s>259</s>, <s>193</s>, <s>181</s>, 179 bytes

```
L(g,n,f)==>[g for i in 1..n|f]
h(a)==(n:=#a;n=1=>a;c:=h(L(a.i,n,odd? i));d:=h(L(a.i,n,even? i));n:=n/2;t:=1>0;v:=L(d.i*%i^(-2*(i-1)/n),n,t);append(L(c.i+v.i,n,t),L(c.i-v.i,n,t)))
```

Even if h(a) could pass all the test and would be ok as entry for this 'competition'
one has to call h() or hlp() thru fft() below, for *checking arguments*.
I don't know if this software can be ok because i only had seen what other wrote, and search
the way it could run in Axiom for return some possible right result. Below ungolfed code with few comments:

```
-- L(g,n,f)==>[g for i in 1..n|f]
-- this macro L, build one List from other list, where in g, there is the generic element of index i
-- (as a.i, or a.i*b.i or a.i*4), n build 1..n that is the range of i, f is the condition 
-- for insert the element in the list result.

hlp(a)==
    n:=#a;n=1=>a
    -- L(a.i,n,odd? i)  it means build a list getting "even indices i of a.i as starting from index 0" [so even is odd and odd is even]
    -- L(a.i,n,even? i) it means build a list getting "odd  indices i of a.i as starting from index 0"
    c:=hlp(L(a.i,n,odd? i));d:=hlp(L(a.i,n,even? i))
    n:=n/2;t:=1>0
    v:=L(d.i*%i^(-2*(i-1)/n),n,t)
    append(L(c.i+v.i,n,t),L(c.i-v.i,n,t))

-- Return Fast Fourier transform of list a, in the case #a=2^n
fft(a)==(n:=#a;n=0 or gcd(n,2^30)~=n=>[];hlp(a))

(5) -> h([1,1,1,1])
   (5)  [4,0,0,0]
                                    Type: List Expression Complex Integer
(6) -> h([1,2,3,4])
   (6)  [10,- 2 + 2%i,- 2,- 2 - 2%i]
                                    Type: List Expression Complex Integer
(7) -> h([5.24626,3.90746,3.72335,5.74429,4.7983,8.34171,4.46785,0.760139])
   (7)
   [36.989359, - 6.2118552150 341603904 + 0.3556612739 187363298 %i,
    1.85336 - 5.744741 %i, 7.1077752150 341603904 - 1.1333387260 812636702 %i,
    - 0.517839, 7.1077752150 341603904 + 1.1333387260 812636702 %i,
    1.85336 + 5.744741 %i,
    - 6.2118552150 341603904 - 0.3556612739 187363298 %i]
                                      Type: List Expression Complex Float
(8) -> h([%i+1,2,%i-2,9])
   (8)  [10 + 2%i,3 + 7%i,- 12 + 2%i,3 - 7%i]
                                    Type: List Expression Complex Integer
```

in the few i had seen h() or fft() would return exact solution, but if the simplification
is not good as in:

```
(13) -> h([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
   (13)
                    +--+                                   +--+
        (- 4 + 4%i)\|%i  - 4 + 4%i             (- 4 - 4%i)\|%i  - 4 + 4%i
   [36, --------------------------, - 4 + 4%i, --------------------------, - 4,
                    +--+                                   +--+
                   \|%i                                   \|%i
            +--+                                   +--+
    (- 4 + 4%i)\|%i  + 4 - 4%i             (- 4 - 4%i)\|%i  + 4 - 4%i
    --------------------------, - 4 - 4%i, --------------------------]
                +--+                                   +--+
               \|%i                                   \|%i
                                    Type: List Expression Complex Integer
```

than it is enought change the type of only one element of list, as in below writing 8. (Float)
for find the approximate solution:

```
(14) -> h([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.])
   (14)
   [36.0, - 4.0000000000 000000001 + 9.6568542494 923801953 %i, - 4.0 + 4.0 %i,
    - 4.0 + 1.6568542494 92380195 %i, - 4.0, - 4.0 - 1.6568542494 92380195 %i,
    - 4.0 - 4.0 %i, - 4.0 - 9.6568542494 923801953 %i]
                                      Type: List Expression Complex Float
```

I wrote it, seen all other answers because in the link, the page it was too much difficult so I don't know if this code can be right. I'm not one fft expert so all this can (it is probable) be wrong.