# Compute convolution quickly and accurately

Tags: fastest-code

## Input

An array A of integers of length 100,000. The array will contain only integers in the range 0 to 1e7.

## Output

The convolution of A with itself. As this will be of length 199999 you should  time just the convolution calculation however, not the time to print out the answer.

## Example in Python

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve
A = np.array([0]+ [1e7]*99999)
B = convolve(A,A, method="direct")
```

If I run this code the convolution line takes about 0.74s. It is over 4s if use a list instead of a numpy array.

## Precision

If I use the numpy FFT method with:

```
convolve(A,A,method="fft")
```

it is very fast but I get the wrong answer due to precision problems.

## Task

Write code to perform convolution that gives the correct output for all inputs in the specified range. Your score will be the factor by which your code is faster than the above code on my computer.

## Computer

I will run your code on Ubuntu on a AMD Ryzen 5 3400G.

## Possible speed ups

Apart from clever coding tricks and parallelization, the following may (or may not) be useful.

- [Karatsuba's](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/what-is-karatsuba-approach-for-efficient-polynomial-multiplication-e033032f2309&ved=2ahUKEwjR-qP4lsaAAxWcxQIHHW0lBbAQFnoECA4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw2CpYyMDg3s4R2YeYfcORO9)  method for polynomial multiplication.
- [Toom Cook multiplication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication#:%7E:text=The%20Toom%E2%80%93Cook%20approach%20to,(%C2%B7)%20at%20various%20points.)
- [The number theoretic transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642152/using-ntt-number-theoretic-transform-to-multiply-two-polynomials)

## Edit

Largest value reduced to 1e7 so that only 64 bit unsigned ints are needed.

## Table of leaders per language

- Score **0.49**. Takes 1.52s in **Python** by **l4m2**
- Score **36**. Takes 0.02s in **C++** by **dingledooper**
- Score **5.3**.  Takes 0.14s in **Rust** by **Bubbler**
- Score **50.3**. Takes 0.015s in **Rust** by **Bubbler** . This is running `ntt_par`.

Comment: But sum(convolution)=sum(A)^2, the checking is bad

Comment: Why not just output the convolution itself?

Comment: Your example result double, inaccurate when testing `A = [1111111111]*100000`

Comment: 100ms C++ should be possible

Comment: Related: [Convolve integers in subquadratic time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67289/20260)

Comment: I don't think the output can fit in 64 bits. How does this play with "accurate"? Does this mean we need to use 128-bit data types?

Comment: @dingledooper I reduced the max size so everything can now fit in 64 bits

Comment: @l4m2 Everything should fit in 64 bit unsigned ints now. 100ms sounds very cool

Comment: not sure I understand, why does your code show a specific array instead of, like, a function or whatever?

Comment: @RubenVerg It's just showing one example input. The code that would be timed is the convolve line

Comment: Possibly relevant existing libraries: FFTW, GMP, [BPAS](https://bpaslib.org).

Comment: Also if someone wants to explore parallel algorithms, there's one like [this (direct pdf link)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.05778)

Answer (score 7):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), ~0.01s

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <immintrin.h>

struct C {
    double x, y;
    C() : x(0), y(0) {}
    C(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    inline C operator+ (const C &c) const { return C(x + c.x, y + c.y); }
    inline C operator- (const C &c) const { return C(x - c.x, y - c.y); }
    inline C operator* (const C &c) const { return C(x * c.x - y * c.y, x * c.y + y * c.x); }
    inline C conj() const { return C(x, -y); }
};

constexpr double PI = acos(-1);
constexpr int SIZE = 100000, B = 32 - __builtin_clz(SIZE * 2 - 1), N = 1 << B;

alignas(32) C w[N >> 2], f0[N], f1[N];

void init_roots() {
    w[0] = C(1, 0);
    for (int len = 1; len < (N >> 2); len <<= 1) {
        C wn(cos(PI / (len << 2)), sin(PI / (len << 2)));
        for (int i = len; i < len << 1; i++)
            w[i] = w[i - len] * wn;
    }
}

__m256d avx_complex_mul(__m256d a, __m256d b) {
    __m256d ax = _mm256_unpacklo_pd(a, a);
    __m256d ay = _mm256_unpackhi_pd(a, a);
    __m256d bs = _mm256_shuffle_pd(b, b, 5);
    return _mm256_fmaddsub_pd(ax, b, _mm256_mul_pd(ay, bs));
}

void fft(C *f) {
    for (int len = N >> 2; len > 1; len >>= 2) {
        for (int i = 0, m = 0; i < N; i += len << 2, m++) {
            double w1x = w[m].x, w1y = w[m].y;
            double w2x = w1x * w1x - w1y * w1y, w2y = 2 * w1x * w1y;
            double w3x = w1x * w2x - w1y * w2y, w3y = w1x * w2y + w1y * w2x;

            __m256d w1 = _mm256_setr_pd(w1x, w1y, w1x, w1y);
            __m256d w2 = _mm256_setr_pd(w2x, w2y, w2x, w2y);
            __m256d w3 = _mm256_setr_pd(w3x, w3y, w3x, w3y);

            constexpr __m256d posneg = { 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0 };

            for (int j = i; j < i + len; j += 2) {
                __m256d c0 = _mm256_load_pd(&f[j + len * 0].x);
                __m256d c1 = avx_complex_mul(_mm256_load_pd(&f[j + len * 1].x), w1);
                __m256d c2 = avx_complex_mul(_mm256_load_pd(&f[j + len * 2].x), w2);
                __m256d c3 = avx_complex_mul(_mm256_load_pd(&f[j + len * 3].x), w3);

                __m256d a02 = _mm256_add_pd(c0, c2);
                __m256d a13 = _mm256_add_pd(c1, c3);
                __m256d s02 = _mm256_sub_pd(c0, c2);
                __m256d s13 = _mm256_xor_pd(posneg, _mm256_sub_pd(c1, c3));
                s13 = _mm256_shuffle_pd(s13, s13, 5);

                _mm256_store_pd(&f[j + len * 0].x, _mm256_add_pd(a02, a13));
                _mm256_store_pd(&f[j + len * 1].x, _mm256_sub_pd(a02, a13));
                _mm256_store_pd(&f[j + len * 2].x, _mm256_add_pd(s02, s13));
                _mm256_store_pd(&f[j + len * 3].x, _mm256_sub_pd(s02, s13));
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0, m = 0; i < N; i += 4, m++) {
        C w1 = w[m], w2 = w1 * w1, w3 = w1 * w2;
        C c0 = f[i + 0], c1 = f[i + 1] * w1,
          c2 = f[i + 2] * w2, c3 = f[i + 3] * w3;
        C a02 = c0 + c2, a13 = c1 + c3,
          s02 = c0 - c2, s13 = (c1 - c3) * C(0, 1);
        f[i + 0] = a02 + a13, f[i + 1] = a02 - a13;
        f[i + 2] = s02 + s13, f[i + 3] = s02 - s13;
    }
}

void ifft(C *f) {
    for (int i = 0, m = 0; i < N; i += 4, m++) {
        C w1 = w[m], w2 = w1 * w1, w3 = w1 * w2;
        C c0 = f[i + 0], c1 = f[i + 1],
          c2 = f[i + 2], c3 = f[i + 3];
        C a01 = c0 + c1, a23 = c2 + c3,
          s01 = c0 - c1, s23 = (c2 - c3) * C(0, 1);
        f[i + 0] = a01 + a23, f[i + 1] = (s01 + s23) * w1;
        f[i + 2] = (a01 - a23) * w2, f[i + 3] = (s01 - s23) * w3;
    }

    for (int len = 4; len < N; len <<= 2) {
        for (int i = 0, m = 0; i < N; i += len << 2, m++) {
            double w1x = w[m].x, w1y = w[m].y;
            double w2x = w1x * w1x - w1y * w1y, w2y = 2 * w1x * w1y;
            double w3x = w1x * w2x - w1y * w2y, w3y = w1x * w2y + w1y * w2x;

            __m256d w1 = _mm256_setr_pd(w1x, w1y, w1x, w1y);
            __m256d w2 = _mm256_setr_pd(w2x, w2y, w2x, w2y);
            __m256d w3 = _mm256_setr_pd(w3x, w3y, w3x, w3y);

            constexpr __m256d posneg = { 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0 };

            for (int j = i; j < i + len; j += 2) {
                __m256d c0 = _mm256_load_pd(&f[j + len * 0].x);
                __m256d c1 = _mm256_load_pd(&f[j + len * 1].x);
                __m256d c2 = _mm256_load_pd(&f[j + len * 2].x);
                __m256d c3 = _mm256_load_pd(&f[j + len * 3].x);

                __m256d a01 = _mm256_add_pd(c0, c1);
                __m256d a23 = _mm256_add_pd(c2, c3);
                __m256d s01 = _mm256_sub_pd(c0, c1);
                __m256d s23 = _mm256_xor_pd(posneg, _mm256_sub_pd(c2, c3));
                s23 = _mm256_shuffle_pd(s23, s23, 5);

                _mm256_store_pd(&f[j + len * 0].x, _mm256_add_pd(a01, a23));
                _mm256_store_pd(&f[j + len * 1].x, avx_complex_mul(_mm256_add_pd(s01, s23), w1));
                _mm256_store_pd(&f[j + len * 2].x, avx_complex_mul(_mm256_sub_pd(a01, a23), w2));
                _mm256_store_pd(&f[j + len * 3].x, avx_complex_mul(_mm256_sub_pd(s01, s23), w3));
            }
        }
    }
}

void convolve(uint64_t *a) {
    init_roots();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        f0[i] = C(a[i] & 4095, a[i] >> 12);
    fft(f0);

    double t0 = 4 * f0[0].x * f0[0].y, t1 = 4 * f0[1].x * f0[1].y;
    f1[0].x = 4 * f0[0].y * f0[0].y, f1[0].y = 0;
    f1[1].x = 4 * f0[1].y * f0[1].y, f1[1].y = 0;
    f0[0].x = 4 * f0[0].x * f0[0].x, f0[0].y = t0;
    f0[1].x = 4 * f0[1].x * f0[1].x, f0[1].y = t1;

    for (int i = 2, msk = 0; i < N; i += 2) {
        msk |= i >> 1;
        int j = i ^ msk;
        C c0 = f0[i] + f0[j].conj();
        C c1 = (f0[i] - f0[j].conj()) * C(0, -1);
        C c00 = c0 * c0, c01 = c0 * c1, c11 = c1 * c1;
        f0[i] = c00.conj() + c01.conj() * C(0, 1), f0[j] = c00 + c01 * C(0, 1);
        f1[i] = c11.conj(), f1[j] = c11;
    }
    ifft(f0); ifft(f1);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE * 2 - 1; i++) {
        uint64_t c0 = (uint64_t) (f0[i].x / (N << 2) + 0.5);
        uint64_t c1 = (uint64_t) (f0[i].y / (N << 2) + 0.5);
        uint64_t c2 = (uint64_t) (f1[i].x / (N << 2) + 0.5);
        a[i] = c0 + (c1 << 13) + (c2 << 24);
    }
}

uint64_t A[SIZE * 2 - 1];

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) A[i] = 1e7;
    clock_t start = clock();
    convolve(A);
    clock_t end = clock();
    uint64_t checksum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE * 2 - 1; i++) checksum ^= A[i];
    printf("checksum: %llu\n", checksum);
    printf("cpu time: %.3fs\n", (double) (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Vltb9s2EP7uX0F0WCHFUipSSYfVToDWyIdiQ1qs35a5gixLiRK9GJYcy8vy15fd8UWiZNlOgwHbhwaBRB7vnjvyIU8XJlgs7OsgeHr6Ic6CZDUPydhPrvNlXN6k54NGGKR@edMSFOU8zsotUd6SlHEa6oI4TcFoGWfHADYoyuUqKMmEPAwI/Mzz1SwJSWWRzYgLJoZJ3pHKcEwQwZM8PEp5oypbG6FZcc1NrRlnSZyF4CFfhEu/zJdDYgR5VqDT14FJRPuBLMNytcwAuCJDEhxjCLyxMUdkB5J9EMlWSPZ@pKODSEeIBDAb3tpYRIgwRiGqttEB5tboQ7OILYJ5HA0GfDisFku1kJ8/kjPiB3lh2NQcaePAG/ny8fcLGKYO/ljkA7RdBnF53mwVJ2WceUHyp8G1jggOUODjEi3IeEw@gD8/ia8zvzBcZkKM66tLcn5O2NQikXN1iS8KL9C7z@M5uIxLb5nnZQETEXtkfeVMAW9iUIs4ptgmUb4kBoaXhBn6GvHGmBgC3JT9MQwpGL6LyDozcKIw5TfEEDqgDiEXcbYllc5aDmNwBxojaIylE3QfD4dmrSyijjFqeMGagN4UlmedCUDgYTDwvJSdvp0T/77ygjxdJGHlpavEqOUWUc2ZmkM9VgG0l2LHW2ULP7hLcm8xN8DGl0HXqpuu6k28Q3VWNKrFzSqKkhA1ZxaB31OpLDeVVItSfz4vVjOOWHFFOQJT4ULYubMCV/JRMhxFpTEhR5GaU4dKQaDg71wRe35@BnxoRLbogG2Z4ktwcomv4ZnihsEgcKPZanlnTSvOUTrFU7umG9XbjHrVGVeneBTxaXMTbMMs1wytmRziwn4QVwNhGghDEHejDeJhV4MVnBAdTZG2phppYbnERQd7SwYlW@ao35j1GLPKksHI1i5jt8fYrfgk8CFaZifuJrsonEVeZOE1YD0Q5xi4tPmzbpLHDkLN/S3YxCN4jZFxcSpvkXrWpVsPO3CasJPcn2PYr6OrW4EAa@1MMbfutscF3zq0e/Ao4iEL@0DZN4IyCcr2gbrfCOpKULdLWiuhONqmgdOPKAFwFewLxafuthHk88DdY1TonmSSOeip0D1VOd@VYodZXSjhvwerhaFlQpBbhD9Oe1dIGsD3PezdVVZnBWApLVyavhj2glEdTKXfl4KxnsgKBCteAOb2RLYL7HHQbj0OBs/M7SdbSX0iEiEmb0ukNehjErZEnhI9NtIMeCKIrjB1OGDEz7Xo0qkw1aLlB1SMMj7KLHG@hMzlMleHF@cEnEBRKZjBLsWuqyMXSs/memLvwebEvmsC7MSARdCTh4oZTzcYDxHbakIXUhulXRuGowW3KRobV0ltlGoliqjIdn6w/0N@dlLTYaVNCK0JAbc@44SwHkJoTQjoFUwQwp5JCDIM2C1CjIKLAcrkk@7lxUBbG21NucE0ejiCXSPULPWVUCeqGr5syuDv1dP36ul/Uz0drJYOFEoHC6MDNdHBGmhv@UP7y5995Z3INR0jdrD8of3lzz5PBXt2@cN2lj9sR/mDWY0//q3yR6ThF5Y/OyrbuoIRuVtU3i@riXZ4qAsuGT4vw19WKO33oM/hGdWT@mJDkrjPk/vQWME5f3vileTIV2dav18Z9XzOxVcAr3M6dxqRIy40JoaPjdfkxPn5FCaAHfiLnaqaHKuFyFH7Q2btErPGCcwaUHAn1C1IdSVtxmg9RuuvSESFiQ6w0QGEwoZHryxoy4LWFlRZ0LaFs@2jCbKyardnMJXaZMtJE7swkU5KOuqpbPHTWtxtf3lb6Rc1/oI8zZe44b/O3@QrqmxXTZysIb5vp8fiWrClhGtuCC27pVXXNzZtWziOKIqOCM9BqkY64jVSQKkobrE72tozYCzhsdhyqOrUpZQlYhCqQqe3zqISjyoIzuWtlKmaiK@Q2oeyRc0@DrTtrm4vxbbXKKgPEV/Z@kyZcv2A9Dd47chvDLEKPD7VIm6Maa/x5nnGrGtMD3r21dKTIf9rAq8pXZN3GDc5MbVKv3b1/kpfDLyWxbVK/Tgzeut/2k0YgMAd0/AngR8keXAHyEXpL0uMCPtqO9ap6r3Z1g6zeVe3WY6bMLgrVql2fp9Ham349YyHKYwXS7CMjFdq9B35MUlWf2SvrNrA7GguVgT/zQGax25UcFX5/wkgB0O3xXRNYGjy66fJL1@8zxe/eV8uJu1bVAevRZ@e/g6ixL8unuxP7pOd@svg5izzy/g@/Ac)

Run with `-O3` or `-Ofast` enabled for best performance. The `-march=native` may also be necessary to run.

Uses a standard floating-point radix-4 FFT. Each input integer is split into two 12-bit chunks to avoid precision loss. Since the input comprises of only real numbers, we can get away with doing just a single FFT by using `a&4095` as the real part and `a>>12` as the imaginary part. Upon converting back we still need two FFTs as the output space is twice as large.

**Update:**

- I realized that the bit reversal was unusually time consuming, so I got rid of it using a DIF-DIT scheme. DIF takes the input in normal order and outputs in bit-reversed order, while DIT takes a bit-reversed input and outputs in normal order. Thus, they magically cancel out :)
- I made another mistake in assuming that `llround` was relatively fast. Apparently adding `+0.5` and then truncating is nearly 10x faster than `llround`, which led to a ~30% improvement.
- Added SIMD in the FFT loop. This one didn't help that much, presumably because GCC already auto-vectorizes it.

Comment: Impressive as usual. I was wondering are you sure this will always give accurate results? Because I tried something similar if more pedestrian (see my deleted post; I also tried 3 (12 bit) and 4 (9 bit) way splitting and padding to a power of two) and never got reliably accurate answers. (fft has a reputation of good accuracy but are there any guaranteed error bounds?)

Comment: @loopywalt Other FFT implementations that I've seen usually chose bases around 2^15, so I thought 2^12 was a safe bet. That said, I tried to test it with some random numbers and the largest difference from rounding after 10000 tests was below 0.001. I don't know how to prove its accuracy, but I suppose some rigorous method exists to test this.

Comment: Thanks, that's good enough for me. (Btw. I found what's wrong with my code. When converting back to int I chose to truncate instead of rounding which makes me wonder how on earth it did sometimes give the correct answer.)

Comment: It's impressive that you made this exactly accurate given that the numpy fft code can't do it.

Comment: @Simd I assume numpy doesn't make any extra effort to improve float accuracy like I do here, but it is at the cost of worse performance. Anyway, I found an interesting method of FFT online that uses radix-4, which seems to be a little faster. I wonder how it performs on your machine.

Comment: That is cool. It seems to run in the same time (although there is some variability). I haven't tried profile guided optimization yet.

Comment: I didn't think the bit reversal step which is normal in FFTs would be very costly. When I timed it it was sometimes taking longer than the FFT itself! I suppose that's a warning to pay attention to cache unfriendly code :P

Comment: @Simd Added SIMD, if you're interested (or know how to optimize it!). I'm assuming that's where your username comes from :P. Should be significantly faster than before, plus all the other optimizations.

Comment: This is very fast!  If I compile with clang++ it is sometimes faster still but the variance is high so it's  hard to measure.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 3 seconds

```python
R = "".join("%028o"%x for x in A)
B = int(R,8)**2 | (1 << 599997*28)
t = oct(B)
G = [int(t[3+i*28:31+i*28],8) for i in range(199999)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU09C4MwEN3zK46AkKSlJEppLHbQxd1VMpTSj3RIRDJY6H9Pc0JBfcvdu/dxwye8vCtiDRfolRFKImKXKKWHt7eO0Uzm2tNsgocfYQLroOakSQ7rAuv2mguRwxeYgqqCY5lwErnmJCSLvwXWcNJiPdpDX@xsUs@FmqdJ8bnXYu94dc87U1hRchOHESNtLw0n/10t95UgN2xLl3z@sNVXATTodIg/)

Was a golfing solution somewhere else but also mine

Comment: That's fascinating code! Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: @Simd Polynomial Multiply and x=8^28

Comment: To explain a bit more, the idea here is that convolution is just long-multiplication where you do the summation step without regrouping, and read off the digits in the end. You can avoid regrouping by working in a high enough base. Here, it's base `8^28`, which is larger than any possible output value.

Answer (score 5):

## Rust + [num-bigint](https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint/tree/master) or [dashu](https://github.com/cmpute/dashu/tree/master), ~0.3 seconds locally

```rust
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use dashu::integer::UBig;
use std::time::Instant;

fn solve_num(input: &[u64]) -> (Vec<u64>, u128) {
    let mut num = Vec::with_capacity(input.len() * 2);
    for &x in input {
        num.push(x as u32);
        num.push(0);
    }
    let big = BigUint::from_slice(&num);
    let instant = Instant::now();
    let big2 = &big * &big;
    let elapsed = instant.elapsed().as_micros();
    (big2.to_u64_digits(), elapsed)
}

fn solve_dashu(input: &[u64]) -> (Vec<u64>, u128) {
    let big = UBig::from_words(input);
    let instant = Instant::now();
    let square = big.square();
    let elapsed = instant.elapsed().as_micros();
    (square.as_words().to_vec(), elapsed)
}

fn main() {
    let input = (
        vec![10_000_000u64; 100_000],
        vec![1; 5]
    ).0;

    let (result, elapsed) = solve_num(&input);
    println!("elapsed: {}.{:06}", elapsed / 1000000, elapsed % 1000000);
    eprintln!("{:?}", result);

    let (result, elapsed) = solve_dashu(&input);
    println!("elapsed: {}.{:06}", elapsed / 1000000, elapsed % 1000000);
    eprintln!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Instructions to run:

- Create a cargo project with `cargo new cg263748`
- Add dependencies in `Cargo.toml`:

  ```
  [dependencies]
  num-bigint = "0.4"
  dashu = "0.3"
  ```
- Replace the content of `src/main.rs` with the source above
- Run with `cargo run --release 2>/dev/null`

Both num-bigint and dashu seem to use "naive/Karatsuba/Toom-3 combo" for inputs with different sizes. For the largest sizes, the main algorithm used is Toom-3. For an input vector of size `10^5`, num-bigint takes ~0.31s and dashu takes ~0.27s.

---

I do have an NTT source code for personal use, but I highly doubt it will be competitive given that a term can go up to `10^19`, which means I have to either use 128-bit multiplication and division in the main algorithm, or convolve twice using two (or maybe three) different modulos and combine them using Chinese Remainder Theorem.

EDIT: Apparently it is possible to do a single NTT with a prime very close to 2^64, using one of the algorithms described [in this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717113001181). e.g. one could choose `p = 10485760000033554433`, where `5` is a primitive root. Unfortunately the faster ones won't work because the prime must be under 2^63 for them.

EDIT 2: I'm working on the NTT implementation on the paper. I realized I need to do elementwise `a * b % P` anyway, so I came up with a "u128 division"-less algorithm ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/snafEn73z)) for a specific P = `71 * 2^57 + 1` = `10232178353385766913`. This is three times as fast as naive `(a as u128 * b as u128 % P as u128) as u64`:

```
slow mulmod             time:   [21.182 ns 21.185 ns 21.188 ns]
fast mulmod             time:   [7.0764 ns 7.1222 ns 7.1864 ns]
```

Comment: Your code seems relatively faster on my computer. Could you add timing code so I am not timing the data creation/startup costs please.

Comment: @Simd The timing code is measuring the correct part of the code. I can't avoid a minimal amount of memory copying to use the library functions, and multiplication is taking 99% of the total time spent anyway.

Comment: Moved the timing sections to measure just the multiplication function itself. My local timings didn't change.

Comment: I love your updates already.

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, ~0.048s locally; Rust + [rayon](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/index.html), ~0.039s locally

The main code (sequential, independent of rayon) is as follows:

```rust
pub const P: u64 = 10232178353385766913;

pub fn mulmod(a: u64, b: u64) -> u64 {
    let x = a as u128 * b as u128;
    let y = x >> 57;
    let y1 = (y >> 35) as u64;
    let y2 = y as u64 & ((1u64 << 35) - 1);
    let y_div_71 = y1 * 483939977 + (y1 + y2) / 71;
    let sub = y_div_71 as u128 * P as u128;
    let (res, borrow) = x.overflowing_sub(sub);
    if borrow { (res as u64).wrapping_add(P) } else { res as u64 }
}

fn powmod(a: u64, p: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut cur = 1;
    let mut pow = a;
    let mut p = p;
    while p > 0 {
        if p % 2 > 0 {
            cur = mulmod(cur, pow);
        }
        p /= 2;
        pow = mulmod(pow, pow);
    }
    cur
}

fn ntt<const INV: bool>(input: &mut [u64], omega_table: &[u64], inv_p2: u64) {
    // length is a power of 2
    let len = input.len();
    let l = len.trailing_zeros() as usize;
    for i in 1..len {
        let j = i.reverse_bits() >> (64 - l);
        if i < j { input.swap(i, j); }
    }

    let mut root_pow = len / 2;
    for intvl_shift in 1..=l {
        let intvl = 1usize << intvl_shift;
        input.chunks_exact_mut(intvl).for_each(|chunk| {
            let mut root_idx = 0;
            let (left, right) = chunk.split_at_mut(intvl / 2);
            for (u, v) in left.into_iter().zip(right) {
                let u2 = *u;
                let v2 = mulmod(*v, omega_table[root_idx]);
                let (mut x, overflow) = u2.overflowing_sub(P - v2);
                if overflow { x = x.wrapping_add(P); }
                *u = x;
                let (mut y, overflow) = u2.overflowing_sub(v2);
                if overflow { y = y.wrapping_add(P); }
                *v = y;
                root_idx = root_idx + root_pow; // & len - 1;
            }
        });
        root_pow /= 2;
    }
    if INV {
        for x in input.into_iter() { *x = mulmod(*x, inv_p2); }
    }
}

fn ntt_precompute(len: usize) -> (Vec<u64>, Vec<u64>) {
    let l = len.trailing_zeros();

    let primitive_root = 3;
    let omega = powmod(primitive_root, P >> l);
    let mut omega_table = vec![1];
    // let mut omega_table_prime = vec![((1u128 << 64) / P as u128) as u64];
    for i in 1..len {
        // omega_table.push((omega_table[i-1] as u128 * omega as u128 % P as u128) as u64);
        omega_table.push(mulmod(omega_table[i-1], omega));
        // omega_table_prime.push((((omega_table[i] as u128) << 64) / P as u128) as u64);
    }
    let mut inv_p2 = 1;
    let mut inv_p2_table = vec![1];
    for _ in 0..l {
        if inv_p2 % 2 == 0 { inv_p2 /= 2; }
        else { inv_p2 = inv_p2 / 2 + P / 2 + 1; }
        inv_p2_table.push(inv_p2);
    }
    (omega_table, inv_p2_table)
}

pub fn solve_ntt(a: &[u64]) -> (Vec<u64>, u128) {
    let instant = Instant::now();

    let len_max = a.len().next_power_of_two() * 2;
    let (mut omega_table, inv_p2_table) = ntt_precompute(len_max);
    let inv_p2 = inv_p2_table[len_max.trailing_zeros() as usize];

    let mut a2 = a.to_vec();
    a2.resize(len_max, 0);
    ntt::<false>(&mut a2, &omega_table, inv_p2);
    for ax in a2.iter_mut() {
        *ax = mulmod(*ax, *ax);
    }
    omega_table[1..].reverse();
    ntt::<true>(&mut a2, &omega_table, inv_p2);
    a2.truncate((a.len() * 2).saturating_sub(1));

    let elapsed = instant.elapsed().as_micros();

    (a2, elapsed)
}
```

This is the version that takes ~0.048s. The code uses NTT (Number Theoretic Transform) with modulo `P = 10232178353385766913 = 71 * 2^57 + 1`. `mulmod` was the major bottleneck until I changed it from u128 multiplication/division to the specialized algorithm for this specific `P`.

I also made three variations using `rayon` to parallelize parts of code when possible, with different heuristics. These versions aren't performing well in my local (which is actually a cloud server with only 2 vCPUs) except for the first, but I believe they'll all outperform the original on better CPUs.

The entire code can be found at https://github.com/Bubbler-4/cg263748. The functions are `solve_ntt`, `solve_ntt_par`, `solve_ntt_par2`, and `solve_ntt_par3` in `lib.rs`.

Run instructions:

- Clone the repo
- `cargo run --release` to see timings and check that the outputs match
- `cargo bench` to run the benchmark using the same input (rayon-powered versions are showing very high variance on my local)

Comment: Could Montgomery multiplication make this faster? You could precompute all the values it needs, as well the the transform of the primitive root.

Comment: @CommandMaster To my understanding, Montgomery may help only when you want `a * b * c * .. * z % p` and nothing in between, which is not the case here (except for `powmod`, but it is used only once during preparing).

Comment: Montgomery also works with addition and subtraction (it is exactly the same as in normal modular arithmetic), so I don't see why you couldn't use it once at the start and reverse it at the end

Comment: @CommandMaster Didn't realize that. Btw, the current version of `mulmod` is already heavily optimized (inspired by Barrett and Lemire reduction), so it's not a major bottleneck anymore.

Comment: ntt_par is the fastest on my computer and it is very fast! I had to clone your repository to be able to compile the code.