# Compute the Discrete Cosine Transform

Tags: code-golf, math, trigonometry

Implement the Discrete Cosine Transform (DCT). This may implemented as either a function or a program and the sequence can be given as either an argument or using standard input. Your program must be able to handle sequences of any length (assuming a hypothetical version of your language which has no limits on things like memory and integer size).

There was a [previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82631/compute-the-discrete-fourier-transform) for DFT, now lets compute DCT! ;-)

Use the [DCT-II definition from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#DCT-II):

[image: DCT-II]

Your program takes a sequence *x*<sub>*n*</sub> as input, and must produce the corresponding sequence *X*<sub>*k*</sub>. In this formula, the cosine is in radians.

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution wins.
- Builtins that compute the DCT in forward or backward (also known as inverse) directions are not allowed.
- Floating-point inaccuracies will not be counted against you.
- You don't have to use the exact algorithm shown here, as long as you produce the same results.

Comment: Mind including an explanation on what DCT is?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#Formal_definition) shows several different versions. Can you please clarify? Voting to close for now.

Comment: @Nick Clifford lets assume DCT-II from that wikipedia page, as it clearly says: The DCT-II is probably the most commonly used form, and is often simply referred to as "the DCT"

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman lets use definition for DCT-II

Comment: @numbermaniac it is DCT-II

Comment: Please add some test cases.

Comment: @Shaggy Producing test cases requires working code, which i, unfortunately, dont have by hand right now.

Comment: @xakepp35 Why not put it into a CAS system like https://www.symbolab.com/ and get test cases from that?

Comment: @numbermaniac too hard to be a challenge. better close it.

Comment: very low people even knows what is it, consider it is kind of alchemistry) its almost impossible to compute DCT, as is impossible to get Au from Hg ;-)

Comment: please, post test cases as you get ones, from working algorithm, i have none by hand and is too silly for using so hard maths. and we could discuss these cases, if that will be actually required ;-)

Comment: @xakepp35 how do we know if our program is correct, if we don't have at least two test cases to test it against? Specifically, `as long as you produce the same results` as what?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
LḶµ+.×þ÷L-*Ḟ³æ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//TOG4tsK1Ky7Dl8O@w7dMLSrhuJ7Cs8OmLv///1sxLCAzLCAyLCA0XQ)

This uses the identity that `cos(pi * x) = real(e^(i * pi * x)) = real((-1)^x)`

### Explanation

```
LḶµ+.×þ÷L-*Ḟ³æ.  Input: array A
L                Length
 Ḷ               Lowered range - [0, 1, ..., len(A)-1]
  µ              Begin a new monadic chain
   +.            Add 0.5
     ×þ          Outer product using multiplication
       ÷         Divide by
        L        Length
         -*      Compute (-1)^x
           Ḟ     Real part
             æ.  Dot product with
            ³    The first argument (A)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 79 bytes

```
Tr/@(s=#;x=Length@s;Table[s[[n+1]]Cos[Pi/x(n+1/2)#],{n,0,x-1}]&/@Range[0,x-1])&
```

Since there are (currently) no test cases, as it turns out, there *is* a built-in for this: `FourierDCT`. However, the function "normalizes" the result by dividing it by a value before returning it. Thankfully, the documentation specifies that this division factor is just the square root of the input list's length (for DCT-II).

So, we can verify our results by multiplying the output of `FourierDCT` by the square root of the length of our input list. For anyone else who tries this problem, here are some test cases:

`FourierDCT@{1,3,2,4}*Sqrt@4`

> {10, -2.38896, 0, -2.07193}

`FourierDCT@{1,1,1,1,1}*Sqrt@5`

> {5, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Note that I've slightly edited the output of the last one; the last four values output as very small decimals, around 10<sup>-16</sup>, due to floating point precision errors around 0. My answer does give 0 for them, if you convert it to a decimal.

This solution gives exact answers when Mathematica can do so. If that's not okay and you want decimals, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>88 83 78</s> 77 bytes

```c
k;d(a,b,c)float*a,*b;{for(k=c*c;k--;)b[k/c]+=a[k%c]*cpow(-1,k/c*(.5+k%c)/c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY7BboMwEETvfMUKKZJt7Boa9eTyJciH9aaOLEhAgapSI369dA3XHnuwPPO8O2MyV6Jt691FoA6aZBxGXBRqFdwzjg/Rt6TI9cY4Gbrekq9a7PoTeUXT@CVMoxkq8fJWMZSWpFu3PQOwa2rvisOEw6T7AjdMdyGfBfBE7dvGsbJ219idM@DNrF99a/bX/A/IqwlaqB1f7zCn748xAtpDKGRcVSAhBwNMD56PAspThFJzU/Igc9bKZ/pcZlGWB7gIQA1BQ1PL/ykLf5WxX4vth@KA13kzw@0X)

This assumes the output vector is cleared before use.

Thanks to [@Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) for -5

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 100 bytes

```
#(for[c[(count %)]k(range c)](apply +(map(fn[n x](*(Math/cos(*(/ c)Math/PI(+ n 0.5)k))x))(range)%)))
```

Sometimes it is difficult to be creative.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>49 46 45</s> 42 bytes

Here we consider the DCT as a matrix multiplication. The matrix is basically the entry-wise cosine of a rank 1 matrix which is very simple to construct.

Thanks @Cowsquack for -1 byte, thanks @ceilingcat for another -3 bytes!

```matlab
@(x)cos(pi/(n=numel(x))*(0:n-1)'*(.5:n))*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCMzm/WKMgU18jzzavNDc1ByiiqaVhYJWna6iprqWhZ2qVBxSo@J@YV6wRbWitC0aGsZr/AQ)

Comment: Can you use `.5` instead of `1/2`?

Comment: D'oh, of course!

Comment: Oh of course, thanks a lot!

Comment: Suggest `rows()` instead of `numel()`

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>51</s> 49 bytes

```
Re@Total[I^Array[(2##+#2)/n&,{n=Length@#,n},0]#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv7/PyjVISS/JDEn2jPOsagosTJaw0hZWVvZSFM/T02nOs/WJzUvvSTDQVknr1bHIFY5Vu1/QFFmXkm0anS1oY6xjpGOSW2svr5f7H8A) (Using Mathics)

Based on my solution to [DFT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82631/compute-the-discrete-fourier-transform/83127#83127).