# Compute the Three Dimensional Discrete Cosine Transform

Tags: math, fastest-code, trigonometry

**Challenge**

I've checked that there is a question [Compute the Discrete Cosine Transform](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/120325/100303) which is a competition for implementing a shortest solution to compute the one dimensional discrete cosine transform.

The goal of this challenge is to implement a program to calculate three dimensional discrete cosine transform which makes processing time as short as possible.

The formula of 3D Discrete Cosine Transform is as below.

[image: 3D Discrete Cosine Transform formula1]

Considering the different size case in three dimension.

[image: 3D Discrete Cosine Transform formula2]

About the accuracy requirement in this challenge, you need to perform the calculation based on double precision floating point.

**Example Input / Output for Performance Evaluation**

Because it is 3D numerical data input / output in this challenge, the structure of input / output data in example is as below.

1. N = 8 :

```
x(0, 0, 0)  x(0, 0, 1)  x(0, 0, 2)  x(0, 0, 3)  x(0, 0, 4)  x(0, 0, 5)  x(0, 0, 6)  x(0, 0, 7)
x(0, 1, 0)  x(0, 1, 1)  x(0, 1, 2)  x(0, 1, 3)  x(0, 1, 4)  x(0, 1, 5)  x(0, 1, 6)  x(0, 1, 7)
...
x(0, 7, 0)  x(0, 7, 1)  x(0, 7, 2)  x(0, 7, 3)  x(0, 7, 4)  x(0, 7, 5)  x(0, 7, 6)  x(0, 7, 7)

x(1, 0, 0)  x(1, 0, 1)  x(1, 0, 2)  x(1, 0, 3)  x(1, 0, 4)  x(1, 0, 5)  x(1, 0, 6)  x(1, 0, 7)
x(1, 1, 0)  x(1, 1, 1)  x(1, 1, 2)  x(1, 1, 3)  x(1, 1, 4)  x(1, 1, 5)  x(1, 1, 6)  x(1, 1, 7)
...
x(1, 7, 0)  x(1, 7, 1)  x(1, 7, 2)  x(1, 7, 3)  x(1, 7, 4)  x(1, 7, 5)  x(1, 7, 6)  x(1, 7, 7)

x(7, 0, 0)  x(7, 0, 1)  x(7, 0, 2)  x(7, 0, 3)  x(7, 0, 4)  x(7, 0, 5)  x(7, 0, 6)  x(7, 0, 7)
x(7, 1, 0)  x(7, 1, 1)  x(7, 1, 2)  x(7, 1, 3)  x(7, 1, 4)  x(7, 1, 5)  x(7, 1, 6)  x(7, 1, 7)
...
x(7, 7, 0)  x(7, 7, 1)  x(7, 7, 2)  x(7, 7, 3)  x(7, 7, 4)  x(7, 7, 5)  x(7, 7, 6)  x(7, 7, 7)
```

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
```

```
360.624 2.81997e-14 -2.88658e-14    4.24105e-14 1.42109e-14 -2.84217e-14    -2.77001e-13    4.26437e-13 
3.10862e-15 3.14018e-16 6.28037e-16 2.51215e-15 0   -1.25607e-15    1.57009e-16 -1.17757e-15    
-1.46549e-14    9.42055e-15 -3.14018e-16    2.19813e-15 -2.19813e-15    -3.14018e-16    1.25607e-15 1.17757e-15 
7.10543e-14 -9.42055e-16    5.0243e-15  -3.14018e-16    0   2.51215e-15 2.51215e-15 1.25607e-15 
2.13163e-14 6.28037e-16 -5.0243e-15 0   -2.51215e-15    -1.09906e-15    0   -1.41308e-15    
-5.01821e-14    -5.65233e-15    4.71028e-15 2.82617e-15 -1.57009e-16    -5.0243e-15 1.17757e-15 -1.13832e-15    
-2.6934e-13 -4.39626e-15    5.49532e-15 1.57009e-16 0   1.09906e-15 2.51215e-15 -1.25607e-15    
4.39315e-13 1.33458e-15 9.42055e-16 2.51215e-15 -1.02056e-15    -1.41308e-15    -2.74766e-16    -3.76822e-15    

-64.9989    -7.22243e-15    8.79252e-15 -2.51215e-15    -1.25607e-15    5.65233e-15 5.66803e-14 -7.87401e-14    
-6.28037e-15    -3.55271e-15    -8.88178e-16    8.88178e-16 8.88178e-16 -8.88178e-16    -1.33227e-15    -6.66134e-16    
3.51701e-14 1.77636e-15 4.44089e-16 -2.66454e-15    4.44089e-16 8.88178e-16 2.22045e-16 3.33067e-16 
2.07252e-14 0   -4.44089e-15    2.22045e-15 4.44089e-16 0   -1.77636e-15    0   
0   1.77636e-15 1.33227e-15 1.33227e-15 -8.88178e-16    -2.22045e-16    -1.33227e-15    4.44089e-16 
1.00486e-14 1.77636e-15 -8.88178e-16    1.33227e-15 -1.11022e-15    2.22045e-16 0   -7.21645e-16    
5.80934e-14 -1.33227e-15    -1.77636e-15    -1.9984e-15 0   -1.11022e-16    -9.99201e-16    8.32667e-16 
-7.96037e-14    1.33227e-15 3.33067e-15 -7.77156e-16    1.11022e-16 4.44089e-16 1.38778e-15 -9.71445e-16    

-4.74731e-13    -6.28037e-16    3.14018e-16 4.71028e-15 -3.76822e-15    -3.76822e-15    3.14018e-15 3.68972e-15 
-4.52187e-14    3.55271e-15 8.88178e-16 -4.44089e-16    -8.88178e-16    0   0   -3.33067e-16    
4.39626e-15 4.88498e-15 -1.33227e-15    8.88178e-16 0   2.22045e-16 -4.44089e-16    -1.88738e-15    
8.16448e-15 1.77636e-15 -1.77636e-15    8.88178e-16 -8.88178e-16    1.77636e-15 -2.22045e-16    7.77156e-16 
6.28037e-16 -1.77636e-15    -1.33227e-15    0   0   -8.88178e-16    -1.44329e-15    1.88738e-15 
-1.25607e-14    -8.88178e-16    3.77476e-15 1.9984e-15  -6.66134e-16    4.44089e-16 2.22045e-15 7.21645e-16 
1.57009e-15 4.88498e-15 -2.22045e-16    1.33227e-15 -9.99201e-16    3.33067e-16 -1.44329e-15    -2.22045e-16    
4.71028e-16 4.21885e-15 6.66134e-16 3.33067e-16 1.66533e-15 -5.55112e-17    2.77556e-16 -6.93889e-16    

-76.6715    2.82617e-15 1.19327e-14 -5.96635e-15    -3.76822e-15    6.90841e-15 5.95065e-14 -8.98093e-14    
-3.14018e-14    2.22045e-15 -1.33227e-15    -4.44089e-16    0   8.88178e-16 -2.22045e-16    6.66134e-16 
2.51215e-14 -4.44089e-16    1.77636e-15 4.44089e-16 0   6.66134e-16 -2.22045e-16    -5.55112e-16    
-3.57981e-14    4.44089e-16 -2.66454e-15    -4.44089e-16    8.88178e-16 0   -1.55431e-15    0   
-8.16448e-15    1.33227e-15 0   1.55431e-15 1.55431e-15 -8.88178e-16    -4.44089e-16    -4.44089e-16    
1.31888e-14 3.10862e-15 -1.11022e-15    -8.88178e-16    6.66134e-16 1.77636e-15 5.55112e-16 -1.4988e-15 
5.68373e-14 0   4.66294e-15 -1.9984e-15 1.11022e-16 2.22045e-16 7.21645e-16 6.10623e-16 
-8.79252e-14    -2.22045e-16    7.77156e-16 9.99201e-16 -5.55112e-16    -1.11022e-15    1.83187e-15 -1.05471e-15    

-4.9738e-14 8.79252e-15 -6.90841e-15    -2.82617e-15    -5.0243e-15 2.35514e-15 -2.51215e-15    -1.57009e-16    
-5.0243e-15 -3.55271e-15    -8.88178e-16    4.44089e-16 -8.88178e-16    -2.22045e-16    6.66134e-16 1.11022e-15 
-1.7585e-14 -5.77316e-15    4.44089e-16 -2.66454e-15    2.22045e-16 -6.66134e-16    3.33067e-16 8.88178e-16 
-5.65233e-15    3.55271e-15 -1.33227e-15    -4.44089e-16    -2.22045e-16    -4.44089e-16    0   -2.22045e-16    
-1.00486e-14    -2.22045e-15    1.9984e-15  2.22045e-16 0   0   0   -2.22045e-16    
3.14018e-16 -2.22045e-16    -8.88178e-16    -6.66134e-16    4.44089e-16 4.44089e-16 2.10942e-15 3.88578e-16 
2.82617e-15 -3.55271e-15    1.77636e-15 1.22125e-15 2.22045e-16 7.77156e-16 1.88738e-15 1.05471e-15 
2.51215e-15 1.9984e-15  2.10942e-15 -1.4988e-15 -9.99201e-16    5.55112e-17 1.11022e-15 2.77556e-16 

-114.747    -3.14018e-14    1.22467e-14 -8.16448e-15    -6.90841e-15    1.00486e-14 8.81607e-14 -1.39149e-13    
-5.0243e-15 -4.44089e-15    0   4.44089e-16 -4.44089e-16    0   -1.22125e-15    -4.996e-16  
-2.51215e-15    5.32907e-15 -8.88178e-16    -1.9984e-15 4.44089e-16 2.22045e-15 -5.55112e-16    -1.66533e-16    
1.57009e-14 2.22045e-16 -4.44089e-16    1.77636e-15 -8.88178e-16    -8.88178e-16    1.11022e-16 -6.10623e-16    
-3.76822e-15    1.77636e-15 -6.66134e-16    0   0   2.22045e-16 -1.66533e-15    4.996e-16   
8.4785e-15  3.77476e-15 6.66134e-16 -1.33227e-15    -1.11022e-16    -8.88178e-16    -1.11022e-16    9.71445e-16 
9.02803e-14 7.21645e-15 -6.66134e-16    -7.77156e-16    1.11022e-16 1.05471e-15 -1.94289e-15    -4.16334e-16    
-1.42957e-13    2.72005e-15 6.10623e-16 -1.66533e-16    7.77156e-16 1.05471e-15 2.77556e-16 1.84575e-15 

-1.00209e-12    6.28037e-16 1.57009e-16 1.25607e-15 1.25607e-15 3.76822e-15 0   -3.76822e-15    
1.41308e-14 -3.77476e-15    -2.44249e-15    0   4.44089e-16 -7.77156e-16    -6.66134e-16    9.4369e-16  
6.59439e-15 6.66134e-16 -1.11022e-15    -1.33227e-15    4.44089e-16 -1.44329e-15    -5.55112e-16    -8.88178e-16    
9.10654e-15 -6.21725e-15    6.66134e-16 -2.22045e-16    4.44089e-16 3.33067e-16 -1.11022e-16    -4.996e-16  
3.14018e-16 2.22045e-15 4.44089e-16 -6.66134e-16    3.33067e-16 -7.77156e-16    3.88578e-16 1.02696e-15 
1.25607e-15 3.10862e-15 5.55112e-16 -4.44089e-16    -5.55112e-16    -1.27676e-15    9.99201e-16 -1.08247e-15    
2.35514e-15 2.77556e-15 -1.22125e-15    2.22045e-16 1.38778e-15 6.10623e-16 1.22125e-15 -1.95677e-15    
-1.31888e-14    2.9976e-15  1.27676e-15 -3.05311e-16    1.08247e-15 -5.82867e-16    -1.26288e-15    5.34295e-16 

-326.772    -3.41495e-14    3.26579e-14 -3.51701e-14    -1.31888e-14    2.51215e-14 2.49174e-13 -3.90796e-13    
-3.18729e-14    -2.66454e-15    -3.21965e-15    -7.77156e-16    -8.88178e-16    8.32667e-16 -1.27676e-15    -1.08247e-15    
5.85644e-14 1.66533e-15 -2.22045e-15    -7.77156e-16    1.88738e-15 7.77156e-16 -1.33227e-15    -1.58207e-15    
-2.32374e-14    3.33067e-15 7.77156e-16 -3.33067e-16    -1.66533e-15    -2.55351e-15    -1.94289e-15    2.498e-16   
-8.16448e-15    3.10862e-15 5.55112e-16 1.27676e-15 1.94289e-15 7.21645e-16 5.55112e-16 1.95677e-15 
2.69271e-14 1.38778e-15 -4.60743e-15    -1.9984e-15 7.21645e-16 3.02536e-15 -2.35922e-15    9.15934e-16 
2.57495e-13 5.93969e-15 -2.94209e-15    1.7486e-15  -8.32667e-17    -8.32667e-16    -9.15934e-16    1.08941e-15 
-3.88284e-13    -1.33227e-15    -1.9984e-15 1.05471e-15 9.29812e-16 7.21645e-16 5.34295e-16 3.66027e-15
```

2. N = 16, N = 25, N = 30 and N = 100

Because the limitation of the body length, the input / output contents of N = 16, N = 25 and N = 30 are as [here](https://gist.github.com/Jimmy-Hu/eb7372b50fb2e97a59c14f3a9b130396). Based on my experiment, when N is up to 25, the run time is about a few seconds.

3. Different size case in each dimension

N1 = 40, N2 = 30, N3 = 20

Note:

- Each test case is run separately (not parallelly) to ensure the computing resource is available.
- The needed compilers and interpreters are installed for testing.

**Winning Criterion & Scores**

This is a [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge, the runtime performance is determined. Scores are from running on my desktop with an AMD 3950x CPU (16C / 32T) and 64GB of 3600MHz RAM.

Comment: How will you time solutions? On a huge amount of data (so parallelising will pay off) or on a single input? Or will you compare single-threaded performance?

Comment: You need to define a requirement on accuracy. Answers may (ab)use loss of accuracy to save time

Comment: Do you have a GPU we can access to increase performance?

Comment: @Adam yes, I’ll install compilers and interpreters if they are needed, for fairness.

Comment: What is the maximum input size that should be supported? Time-efficient approaches tend to be memory-hungry

Comment: So basically it's about implementing the [VR DIF algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#3-D_DCT-II_VR_DIF) which has O(n^3 log n) time complexity, though I'm not sure if it works with non-power-of-2 dimensions.

Comment: I'd highly recommend the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) the first few (or many) times you write challenges, but even more so for non-[tag:code-golf] challenges, as these are notoriously hard to get right.

Comment: I also recommend answering a few existing challenges that have the same winning criteria as the challenges you contemplate posting, as this will give you a sense of the kind of details one needs to write an answer to that type of challenge.

Comment: > On a huge amount of data (so parallelising will pay off) or on a single input?

Each test case is run separately (not parallelly)

Comment: > What is the maximum input size that should be supported? Time-efficient approaches tend to be memory-hungry
There are 6 test cases listed above. Performance measurement is based on these test cases.

Comment: > You need to define a requirement on accuracy. Answers may (ab)use loss of accuracy to save time

About the accuracy requirement in this challenge, you need to perform the calculation based on double precision floating point.

Comment: > I'd highly recommend the Sandbox the first few (or many) times you write challenges, but even more so for non-code-golf challenges, as these are notoriously hard to get right.

This challenge has been posted [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20754/100303) for few days.

Comment: > Do you have a GPU we can access to increase performance?

I have no way to compare it in this challenge but it would be great to have a GPU answer. :)

Comment: Sorry about the sandbox comment. I should have checked. However, you went ahead and posted the challenge despite having no upvotes in the sandbox, nor did you have multiple people say it was ready to go. I know it is difficult to get enough feedback in the sandbox. Asking (multiple times, at different times of the day and week) for review in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) can help.

Comment: @Adám > However, you went ahead and posted the challenge despite having no upvotes in the sandbox, nor did you have multiple people say it was ready to go. I know it is difficult to get enough feedback in the sandbox. Asking (multiple times, at different times of the day and week) for review in the chat room can help. I see. Thank you for the suggestion. :)